# java calendar returns wrong week

Tags: java, calendar

I have the following test that from my understanding should pass. Is there something I'm missing or is this a bug in Calendar?

```java
Calendar inputC = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.US);  

// Sunday  
inputC.set(2014, Calendar.JUNE, 22, 0, 0, 0);  
inputC.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  

// START code impl
// Given a date returns back the date with it's day being first day of week and resets time.  
Calendar dc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.US);  
dc.set(inputC.get(Calendar.YEAR), inputC.get(Calendar.MONTH), inputC.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0 , 0);  
dc.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  
// dc.getTimeInMillis();  
// dc.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, inputC.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));  
dc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dc.getFirstDayOfWeek());  

Date output = dc.getTime();  
// END code impl

Calendar expectedSundayC = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.US);  
expectedSundayC.set(2014, Calendar.JUNE, 22, 0, 0, 0);  
expectedSundayC.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  

assertEquals(output, expectedSundayC.getTime());
```

Output:     2014-06-**15**T00:00:00Z
Expected: 2014-06-**22**T00:00:00Z

The above test fails unless I uncomment either one of the 2 following lines:

```java
// dc.getTimeInMillis();  
// dc.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, inputC.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Why is that `dc.getTimeInMillis()` affects the output?
Uncommenting line 2 above seems redundant because I already set year,month,day,hour,minute,seconds, milliseconds fields which should be enough data for complete datetime.

Comment: I get the feeling it's the second line that affects the output, not the `dc.getTimeInMillis()`... You could try setting it to `inputC.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + 1`?

Comment: Like I said, any of the 2 lines affect the output. I can just uncomment only `dc.getTimeInMillis()` and the test passes.

Comment: Day of week and first day of week are not the same thing.

Comment: Why do you setting `DAY_OF_WEEK` at all?

Comment: If you read the comment for the part of code that is tested it says that the scope of the code is to get a date and set the day to be first day of week.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You certainly gave me a headscratcher on this one, but I figured it out.

#### Specifications

[From the JavaDoc:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

> The calendar field values can be set by calling the set methods. Any field values set in a Calendar will not be interpreted until it needs to calculate its time value (milliseconds from the Epoch) or values of the calendar fields. Calling the get, getTimeInMillis, getTime, add and roll involves such calculation.

What this means is that, whenever you change your values using set, you should tell it to update itself by using one of the get methods to propagate changes. However, your code didn't, except when you uncommented the code. So something in your code was obviously not playing well with your sets in the computeTime.

#### Where Things Went Bad

So... we can look at this *out-of-date but nevertheless still monstrously hard-to-navigate copy of* [GregorianCalendar](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/GregorianCalendar-source.html) source and analyze exactly what's happening when you do the getTime() after setting the day of week with all the other chanes.

Ugh, copying from that is a pain. I'll walk you through it.

First, we basically know that `getTimeInMillis()` calls `computeTime()` at line `505`.

You declared an instance of Calendar. It has predefined values. Today's date to be exact. And also we are in the third week of September. Important later!

Now we assign your day at line `511`. This is where your day is set to 22.

```
int day = fields[DAY_OF_MONTH];
```

Line `523` is where things go bonkers and break your date! We evaluate this to be `false` and go to the else at line `553`.

```
if (! isSet[MONTH] && (! isSet[DAY_OF_WEEK] || isSet[WEEK_OF_YEAR]))
//evaluates to true
```

We enter the if statement at `555` because `DAY_OF_WEEK` is set. And we have a `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`, but we didn't set it ourselves. Calendar did when it was instantiated. Remember that 3rd week of September? Yup, it's here where it bites us back. It calculates the Sunday of the 3rd week in June and *overwrites our day = 22* to the 15th, which is the 3rd Sunday in the week of June.

```
    if (isSet[DAY_OF_WEEK]) { //yup we set this
        int first = getFirstDayOfMonth(year, month);

        // 3: YEAR + MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
        if (isSet[DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH]) { //we didn't set this, but it's been set!
            if (fields[DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH] < 0) { 
                month++;
                first = getFirstDayOfMonth(year, month);
                day = 1 + 7 * (fields[DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH]);
            } else
                day = 1 + 7 * (fields[DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH] - 1); 
                 // 15 = 1 + 7 * (3 - 1)

            int offs = fields[DAY_OF_WEEK] - first;
            if (offs < 0)
                offs += 7;
            day += offs;
        }
    }
```

#### How We Can Solve the Problem

Check the source javadoc on the `set` method you called with year, month, and day.

> Sets the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR_OF_DAY, and MINUTE. **Previous values of other fields are retained.** If this is not desired, call clear() first.

Sure enough, adding `dc.clear();` before your set returns the desired result. I didn't walk through it, but *given the weird behavior currently experienced* the best bet would be to `getTime()` after each change will make sure your time doesn't become an unexpected result.

So basically, what was causing the problem was that you had half-dirty data with half-new data that contradicted itself and overwrote things. If this code had been run next week, you *wouldn't have even caught the bug.* How's that for an inconvenient time-dependent condition?

Comment: Ugh, the more I deal with Calendar, the more I realise the whole thing needs to be deprecated... nicely figured out though!

Comment: @berry120: As an aside, Java 8 makes improvements to the Date API, as well as Joda Time being commonplace for people dealing with times.  Both are very strong Date APIs, which deal with immutable instants of time (thus preventing you from getting into this situation to begin with).

Comment: @Makoto Oh I know, the new `java.time` package is a *huge* improvement - hence why I think all of `Calendar` should now be buried!

Comment: Incidentally, one little used feature of `Calendar` objects is the `setLenient()` method - I always set it to false, and then it will always catch things like this and throw exceptions (rather than trying to guess a better date!)

Comment: Good find and explanation. Only thing is that on my machine the implementation of GregorianCalendar is different. The GregorianCalendar on my machine has over 3k lines and the computeTime function is a mess 3 times as long as the one you linked. My java version `java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)`

Comment: Verified that the impl on my machine matches openjdk impl from: http://www.java.net/download/openjdk/jdk7u40/promoted/b43/openjdk-7u40-fcs-src-b43-26_aug_2013.zip

Comment: @Ioan-CristianLinte The relevant code is in `getFixedDate()`, called by `computeTime()` (it's slightly different, but essentially doing the same thing.)